# Getting a "There is no registered service of type" error even though I have the service registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor

I'm trying to work with dependency injection and I added a singleton and transient service to the `IServiceCollection`, however, when I try to run the application and open the page that utilized the DI, it just gives me an error saying:

> An unhandled error has occurred. Reload

, and if I open the dev tools, it shows me a long error, mentioning the issue I stated in the title

*The program file:*

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using blazorTestApp.Client;


var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

await builder.Build().RunAsync();

ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceAdder)
{
    serviceAdder.AddSingleton<SingletonService>();
    serviceAdder.AddTransient<TransientService>();
}
```

*The file using the DI:*

```
@page "/counter"
@inject TransientService trans
@inject SingletonService single

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @trans.value</p>
<p role="status">Current count: @single.value</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        trans.value++;
        single.value++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to move the caller `ConfigureServices(builder.Services);` before the line: `await builder.Build().RunAsync();`?

Comment: That.... was the issue, can't believe I missed that lmao

thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the caller `ConfigureServices(builder.Services);` before the line `await builder.Build().RunAsync();`.

When the `WebApplicationBuilder` is instantiated, the services are added to the DI Container.

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Reference: [Dependency injection (services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows#dependency-injection-services)